# Android promo code implementation and counting use

Tags: android, promotion-code

I've implemented a promo code feature in the free version of an app I published which unlocks the content available in the full version. I plan on sharing this with friends/family and would like a way to get a count on how many times the promo code is used. Is there a simple way to do this without involving a mail server?

Answer (score 0):

Use WebServices, everytime that someone uses your promotion code, make a HTTP Post in your server, then in your server count every HTTP Post. You will know how many times this promo code is used